# Display all dataframe columns in a Jupyter Python Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I want to show all columns in a dataframe in a Jupyter Notebook. Jupyter shows some of the columns and adds dots to the last columns like in the following picture:

[image: Juputer Screenshot]

How can I display all columns?

Answer (score 275, accepted):

Try the display `max_columns` setting as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

df = pd.read_csv("some_data.csv")
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
display(df)
```

Or

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

**Pandas 0.11.0 backwards**

This is deprecated but in versions of Pandas older than 0.11.0 the `max_columns` setting is specified as follows:

```
pd.set_printoptions(max_columns=500)
```

Comment: If you want to make a temporary setting, you can use e.g. `with pd.option_context("display.max_rows", 10, "display.max_columns", 5):` (see [Getting and setting options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#getting-and-setting-options)).

Comment: This is old but do you happen to know if there is a way to set this by default ?

Comment: once you execute this, all your `display()` will fail elsewhere

Answer (score 46):

I know this question is a little old but the following worked for me in a Jupyter Notebook running pandas 0.22.0 and Python 3:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', <number of columns>)
```

You can do the same for the rows too:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', <number of rows>)
```

This saves importing IPython, and there are more options in the pandas.set_option documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html

Comment: You can use the None keyword in <number of columns> if you don't know the number of columns beforehand.

Comment: For some reason none of the  pd.set_option and pd.options.display.max_columns = None worked for me. Only the solution with HTML worked. I'm using Python 3.8.5.0, pandas 1.1.3 and jupyter core=4.6.3 with jupyter-notebook : 6.1.4. Any idea why those solutions are not working?

Answer (score 14):

I recommend setting the display options inside a context manager so that it only affects a single output. I usually prefer "pretty" html-output, and define a function `force_show_all(df)` for displaying the DataFrame `df`:

```py
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

def force_show_all(df):
    with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None, 'display.width', None):
        display(HTML(df.to_html()))

# ... now when you're ready to fully display df:
force_show_all(df)
```

As others have mentioned, please be **cautious** to only call this on a reasonably-sized dataframe.

Answer (score 11):

## Python 3.x for large (but not too large) DataFrames

Maybe because I have an older version of pandas but on Jupyter notebook this work for me

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.core.display import HTML

df=pd.read_pickle('Data1')
display(HTML(df.to_html()))
```

Comment: Tried this but it ruined my jupyter session going out of memory. My PC has SSD and 8 GB RAM memory...

Comment: @FLBKernel it has not done this to me, maybe your Dataframe is much larger than mine. What was your way out? Did you try another method and worked for you? if so share your knowledge. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't found any method yet, but I will let you know as soon as I get to solve this problem. 
And yes, my Dataframe was probably larger so lets point out that this is not recomendable for large Dataframes

Comment: @FLBKernel My data frame was also large. But I did not know to what extent large it can be. I will point it out. Thanks!

Comment: Mine has 107.763 rows and 15 columns. We can establish -maybe- that more than about 100k rows and 15 columns this answer is not recomendable.
I like the "large (but not too large)" title though :)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to show all the rows set like bellow

```
pd.options.display.max_rows = None
```

If you want to show all columns set like bellow

```
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use pandas.set_option(), for column, you can specify any of these options

```
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 200)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 100)
pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", 200)
```

For full print column, you can use like this

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
print(words.head())
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This can help you:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```