# Maximum number of columns for a particular dataframe (view in Jupyter Lab)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a following question. When I work with a particular dataframe (e.g. example below, with 8 first columns..) in Jupyter Lab, I am currently constantly having the problem of display of maximum number of columns (I have currently in the table around 30 variables which I would like to have in the dataframe table simultaneously as columns, and the number of variables (columns) which I would like to keep in the dataframe table constantly keeps increasing..). I have already used the following possibilities:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
df1=df1.drop(['c'], axis=1) (to manually drop unnecessary variables)
```

Is there any other possibility (workaround) which could allow me to save space and to increase even more the number of columns which I can have simultaneously in the dataframe?
Thanks in advance

```
df1.head(1)
date        c       r       Crit1   Crit2   cr1     p1  p2    sg    ...
2020-05-29  317.94  0.00    1.80    2.80    1.00    1   0.0   1.0
```

(In case, should I also try to cut as well all the column names (to 1-2 symbols max) and column values (to put them to integer values where possible))?

Comment: this is a broad and a bit too vague question… there are many ways to rework your names but it's up to you in the end… If you want to display only one row you can use `df1.iloc[0]` to get a long format as Series

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display all dataframe columns in a Jupyter Python Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47022070/display-all-dataframe-columns-in-a-jupyter-python-notebook)

Comment: Thank you! I was just wondering if for the current setup (to gain space/maximize the number of columns which can be simultaneously viewed..) any of the following parameters can be changed: e.g column width, font, number of pixels per column, or any other..?