# how to increase width output cell in Vs code jupyter?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

[image]

How to increase the width so that the dataframe fits completely?

Comment: This covered in many places on here already. Please research your question before posting a new one. Also you don't probably want to print a dataframe in Jupyter. The point of using Jupyter is to take advantage of the conveniences of Jupyter's GUI. By bracketing your viewing of dataframe in `print()` you are telling it to just look at it like you are using a text based terminal. Usually you'd call `display(dataframe)` if you aren't putting it on the last line of the cell. I cannot tell what you have made from your chunking approach since you share code as a screenshot.

Comment: See things like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47022213/8508004). Try working through the guide  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47022213/8508004) to learn more about the display options built in.  Please read and follow [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the sections about researching your issue and 'Help others reproduce the problem'.